# Admob ad requests in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, request, admob, banner

At the start of my game I am loading a banner Ad, but due to the implementation of admob for Unity it stays throughout all scenes. So my question is: 
To maximize revenue should I hide the ad and request a new one, or if I tweak the refresh rate ( of the banner ad ) it would be the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean a normal (320x50) banner or interstitial at the start? Anyway important is: 1) if its an interstitial at launch - it's not suitable for AdMob and u can have troubles. 2) If your app is a game, banners (320x50) are crap in that case, cause they get on gamers' nerves and have low cpm. I advice u to use videos and interstitials. The point is to place them correctly, so that users see them and feel comfortable. To maximize revenue you'd better use mediating platforms: Appodeal, MobFox or Supersonic. I personally really like the first one cause it's fillrate and average cpm for vids and intrsttls  is the higest. I judge by my clicker game on Android.